# LibGdx not scaling to whole screen

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

In my LibGdx game I have it using a ExtendedViewport

```
 new ExtendViewport(LevelSmash.WIDTH, LevelSmash.HEIGHT, camera);
```

I set a width of 708, and height of 900,

In my render method i scale the spritebatch to the projection of the viewport

```
    @Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

    sb.setProjectionMatrix(vp.getCamera().projection);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    sb.begin();
    level.render(sb);
    sb.end();

    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

The level's render method is

```
    @Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(vp.getCamera().projection);
    sb.draw(background, 0 / LevelSmash.PPM, 0 / LevelSmash.PPM);

    player.draw(sb);
}
```

**PPM is equal to 100**

I want the background to take the whole screen since its the width and height i scaled everything to (708, 900)

But it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your camera is centered on `0, 0` and your texture starts drawing at `0, 0` to `708, 900`. Best to set your camera's center to the center of the image.

```
camera.position.set(LevelSmash.WIDTH / 2, LevelSmash.HEIGHT / 2);
camera.update();
```

**EDIT**

I find it strange that the brackground is being drawn at all.

```
sb.draw(background, 0 / LevelSmash.PPM, 0 / LevelSmash.PPM);
// 0 / X == 0 so width and height are always 0;
```

Can you explain this? Since it's hard to believe you see anything being drawn by that line.

Comment: I tried adding that to the first render method and didn't change anything?

Comment: That's probably because you are using only the projection matrix and not the combined matrix (`sb.setProjectionMatrix(vp.getCamera().combined);`). You also need to implement the `resize` method, see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports. And should ditch the `PPM` stuff, see: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels/

Comment: I don't have a resize method because none of my classes extend ApplicationAdapter so i do not know where it belongs, i changed it to combined but doesn't change anything, sorry if im missing something obvious sorta new to this. [Code: http://pastebin.com/Nxn8hjF9 ]